# Invoking code when opening window/stage JavaFX

Tags: java, scala, javafx

I'm making a piece of software that needs to load data from a settings file, or a de-serialised object of said file when the window opens, is there some sort of *"onOpen"* method you can override, so you can execute some code when the window is loading? À la the `MainWindow` method in `WPF`. The window is made in `FXML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following to your controller, it is automatically called after the fxml file has been loaded.

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
/* insert code here */
}
```